# Godot is failing to load a .pck file on a python flask server; can anyone suggest a fix?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, godot

Looking for some advice concerning running a Godot game over a flask server. I've uploaded the relevant code here: https://github.com/philhteoma/godotTestSite

Currently, the game functions perfectly fine in the browser if I run a simple http python server. However, running it through flask has caused quite a few issues. I've gotten it to the point where the actual javascript code runs, but when the game tries to start I get the following error:

```
Error: Couldn't load project data at path ".". Is the .pck file missing?
```

I've changed the EXECUTABLE_NAME and MAIN_PACK variables to a lot of different values, and I've ensured that they are getting passed through to the engine correctly. I'm guessing this could be a permission or pathing error based in flask, but I don't even know where to look any more. Has anyone got any ideas on what could be wrong, or how to fix this?